# Performing Sum in INNER JOINING using GROUP BY function Not Working Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can any one explain why I'm still getting a separated of 2 same column name even if I already use sum and group by clause?

Here is my query in postgres:

```sql
SELECT tbl_boxes.box_name                          AS "BOX NAME",
       tbl_stores.store_name                       AS "STORE NAME",
       tbl_sku.sap_name                            AS "SKU NAME",
       SUM(tbl_bad_orders_product.quantity_pcs)    AS "QUANTITY PER PIECE",
       SUM(tbl_bad_orders_product.price_per_piece) AS "PRICE PER PIECE",
       SUM(tbl_bad_orders_product.quantity_cs)     AS "QUANTITY PER CASE",
       SUM(tbl_bad_orders_product.price_per_case)  AS "PRICE PER CASE",
       tbl_bad_orders_product.reason               AS "REASON",
       SUM(tbl_bad_orders_product.total_amount)    AS "TOTAL AMOUNT",
       tbl_bad_orders_product.date_created         AS "DATE CREATED",
       tbl_bad_orders_product.date_updated         AS "DATE UPDATED",
       tbl_bad_orders_product.date_sync            AS "DATE SYNCED"
FROM tbl_bad_orders_product
       INNER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_bad_orders_product.tbluserid = tbl_users.tbluserid
       INNER JOIN tbl_boxes ON tbl_bad_orders_product.tblboxid = tbl_boxes.tblboxesid
       INNER JOIN tbl_stores ON tbl_bad_orders_product.tblstoreid = tbl_stores.tblstoreid
       INNER JOIN tbl_sku ON tbl_bad_orders_product.tblskuid = tbl_sku.tblskuid
WHERE tbl_bad_orders_product.date_sync::date >= '2019-02-19'
  AND tbl_bad_orders_product.date_sync::date <= '2019-02-19'
GROUP BY tbl_boxes.box_name, tbl_stores.store_name, tbl_sku.sap_name, tbl_bad_orders_product.quantity_pcs,
         tbl_bad_orders_product.price_per_piece, tbl_bad_orders_product.quantity_cs,
         tbl_bad_orders_product.price_per_case, tbl_bad_orders_product.reason, tbl_bad_orders_product.total_amount,
         tbl_bad_orders_product.date_created, tbl_bad_orders_product.date_updated, tbl_bad_orders_product.date_sync
ORDER BY tbl_boxes.box_name ASC
```

But im getting this output:

[image]

Please help me how to fix it.

Comment: [why-not-upload-images-of-code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: groupped by `tbl_bad_orders_product.price_per_piece`

Comment: @BearBrown already have it in group by clause

Comment: yes and it is your trouble)

Comment: @BearBrown how's that become my trouble?

Comment: you have different values of the `price_per_piece` for the same `box_name`

Comment: @BearBrown but i performed sum function to it.

Comment: @BearBrown still getting same result i added sum() function

Comment: You need to remove `price_per_piece ` from the group by clause

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you are including the same aggregated columns in `SELECT` from *tbl_bad_orders* (*quantity_pcs*,  *price_per_piece*, *quantity_cs*, *price_per_case*, *total_amount*) within the `GROUP BY` clause which almost devoids the need for aggregation since you run an aggregate function, `SUM`, grouped by its very value.

Simply remove these numeric fields used in `SUM` aggregation from the `GROUP BY` clause. Also, consider table aliases for readability and maintainability. Consider also re-ordering fields in `SELECT` for grouped columns on left hand side and aggregated columns on right hand side of resultset. Finally, your `WHERE` condition may be redundant.

```
SELECT b.box_name                  AS "BOX NAME",
       s.store_name                AS "STORE NAME",
       sku.sap_name                AS "SKU NAME",
       bad.reason                  AS "REASON",
       bad.date_created            AS "DATE CREATED",
       bad.date_updated            AS "DATE UPDATED",
       bad.date_sync               AS "DATE SYNCED",
       SUM(bad.quantity_pcs)       AS "QUANTITY PER PIECE",
       SUM(bad.price_per_piece)    AS "PRICE PER PIECE",
       SUM(bad.quantity_cs)        AS "QUANTITY PER CASE",
       SUM(bad.price_per_case)     AS "PRICE PER CASE",
       SUM(bad.total_amount)       AS "TOTAL AMOUNT"
FROM tbl_bad_orders_product AS bad
     INNER JOIN tbl_users AS u ON bad.tbluserid = u.tbluserid
     INNER JOIN tbl_boxes AS b ON bad.tblboxid = b.tblboxesid
     INNER JOIN tbl_stores AS s ON bad.tblstoreid = s.tblstoreid
     INNER JOIN tbl_sku AS sku ON bad.tblskuid = sku.tblskuid
WHERE bad.date_sync::date >= '2019-02-19'
  AND bad.date_sync::date <= '2019-02-19'
GROUP BY b.box_name, 
         s.store_name, 
         sku.sap_name, 
         bad.reason,
         bad.date_created, 
         bad.date_updated, 
         bad.date_sync
ORDER BY b.box_name ASC
```